# WPF/XAML event handler binding in style with view model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, styles

I created my calendar with style:

```
<Style x:Key="CalendarDayButtonStyle" TargetType="CalendarDayButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Brush.Foreground.TextBlock.LightBlue}" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Template"> 
        ...

        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="{Binding DayButtonCommand}"/>
    </Style>
```

and I want to perform the command by MouseDoubleClick Event.

But at the start of the application exception occurs:
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: BaseUri can be set only once at the root node (the XamlXmlReader possibly a default value is provided at the root node)."

I create this Style in resource file and work with MVVM.

How can I bind MouseDoubleClick event with this Style for CalendarDayButton?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use a style for this but rather use an attached behavior to fire a command when the Double Click event is fired. [MVVM light has such a feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx).

The XAML looks like this :

```
<CalendarDayButton ...>

   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
        <command:EventToCommand
            Command="{Binding Main.NavigateToArticleCommand,
            Mode=OneWay,
            Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" />
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
 </CalendarDayButton>
```

EDIT : you can also use a Routed EventHandler on the Calendar object in the View, and call the ViewModel command from the view's codebehind. [Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742550%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I already tried so, but XAML write "Property 'Triggers' is not attachable to elements of type 'Style'".

Comment: I repeat what I said, you shouldn't use a style for this. Maybe use an event Handler on the Calendar object, and fire the ViewModel command from the view code-behind. [See this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742550%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: A very good idea. I did this in View with Calendar and in code-behind I call ViewModell. Thank you very much

Comment: And did it work? If it did you may now accept the answer and close the question.